# 'Cat' has a final 't'. — The letter "t" is the only one in the word "cat". Then why is it possible to use "a" here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference, articles

[collinsdictionary.com](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/final):
**(1)** *'Cat' has **a** final 't'*.

The letter "t" is the only one in the word "cat".
Then why is it possible to use "a" here?

my variant:
**(2)** *'Cat' has **the** final 't'*.

Is (2) correct?
If not , then why not?
If it is, then what is the difference between (1) and (2)?

Comment: The same difference as always: **a** is general and **the** is specific. And you would have to specify how the t is specific, which I am not going to rack my brain to come up with.

Comment: There are more written instances of *[some word]* [*ends with **the** letter 'b'*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22ends+with+the+letter+b%22) than there are of [*...ends with **a** letter 'b'.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22ends+with+a+letter+b%22) But they're both fine, and I'd say almost always interchangeable. Your variant (2) *isn't* natural though - you can use ***a*** without the word ***letter***, but that doesn't work with ***the*** (it has to be *...ends with the final letter 't'*).

Comment: What I find really interesting is that the Collins Dictionary uses a lower case c on cat. **'cat' has a final t**. This issue came up on the Spanish site because everyone there wanted to put a word as found in the dictionary at the beginning of the sentence with a capital letter. However, dictionary entries don't have capital letters. Ergo, when explaining a word as found in a dictionary in single quote marks, you would not use a capital letter. Spanish rules say sentences start with a cap but they say nothing about a reference to a dictionary word as the first word in the sentence...

Comment: "Cat has a final t", "The house has a billiard room", "A monkey has a long tail", "Milan has a world-famous opera house", "My mum has a bad back". "a" is standard with "have"/"has".

Comment: When speaking about the spelling of a word, you might say "The final letter of 'Cat' is a T" or "is T" but not "The final letter of cat is the T."

Comment: @user8356 It's best to use lower case. Cat with a capital c is not in the dictionary...

Comment: @Lambie The lower case used in the headword serves a purpose, which is to let the reader know that no capital is required at the beginning of that word (unlike in “_Freudian_”, for instance). Just as there’s no need to write “cat” in boldface or in black ink to imitate the dictionary’s entry, capitals required by proper typography in other circumstances need not be affected by this, which would be irrelevant in most cases.
See for instance how Collins writes “Final means happening at the end of an event or series of events” [here](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/final).

Comment: @Philippe-AndréLorin Why are you repeating to me what I already said?? I used bold so the sentence would stand out.

Comment: How about "the letter _t_ is doubled in the word _letter_"?  There are two _t_'s, yet we use the singular.

Comment: @Lambie I am not. You wrote: “when explaining a word as found in a dictionary in single quote marks, you would not use a capital letter” and “cat with a capital c is not in the dictionary”, and I’m detailing why this is wrong. Surely you did not “already say” that you were wrong and why, or did you? Also I’m not referring to the fact that you wrote “'cat' has a final t” in boldface.

Comment: @Philippe-AndréLorin That's right. The Collins Dictionary is right. Go look at the link in the question and you will see that the sentence 'Cat' has a final 't' is given as 'cat' has a final 't'.

Comment: @Lambie The initial lowercase in “'cat' has a final 't'” is due to the same typographical choice as the initial lowercases in “a final decree of judgment” or “a final clause may be introduced by 'in order to'”, not whatever idea you came up with that no style guide or manual of typography mentions.

Comment: !@Philippe-AndréLorin If you cite a word from a dictionary as the first word in your sentence, it is not capitilized. Just like the Collins Dictionary does not capitalize it. 'cat' has a final t. If you capitalize it, you are no longer citing the word *as it appears in a dictionary*. It is not an idea I came up with. It is how the Collins Dictionary writes the sentence. "manuel of typography mentions" sounds French...

Comment: @Lambie If this isn’t an idea you came up with, please do share your sources. My English might not be perfect (I didn’t write “manuel”, though; and, if you do want to play that silly game: “capitilized” is not English), but typographical matters, both English and French, have been my job for fifteen years, and I’ve never encountered this idea. On the other hand, your lack of typographical knowledge or care is obvious, not only from your argument, but also from your writing (typewriter apostrophes, missing italics). Thus, as you’re only repeating yourself, I won’t take the discussion further.

Comment: @Philippe-AndréLorin To tell you the truth, this annoyed me: If this isn’t an idea you came up with, please do share your sources. So I started typing fast and that causes typos. **As I have said several times, the Collins Dictionary entry is my source**.  What is your issue with it??

Comment: @lambie You never said Collins was your source. It cannot be, as it does not _say_ what you say. It _does_ something that _coincides_ with what you say. You noticed the lowercase in “cat” and came up with a hypothesis about why this _c_ is lowercase. The hypothesis is your idea, Collins says nothing about it. And your hypothesis can be rejected based on Occam’s razor, as the lowercase _c_ can be explained by the same rule that would explain why, in the same Collins entry, “a final decree of judgment”, “a final clause may be introduced by 'in order to'”, etc. start with a lowercase.

Comment: @Philippe-AndréLorin Wrong, I did say it: Look at my second comment: What I find really interesting is that the Collins Dictionary uses a lower case c on cat. 'cat' has a final t.  Think about this: cat is in the dictionary, *Cat* is not. Ergo, starting a sentence with  'cat' means lowercase, as **in the dictionary**.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In short, because there are many final 't's. Bat, cat, format, splat — each has a final 't'. That means that cat's final 't' in this sense is one of many, which we express with the indefinite article.

If you're referring specifically to the 't' in "cat", then you would use the definite article:

- "Cat" has **a** final 't'.
- **The** 't' in "cat" is final.
- **The final 't'** in "target" should be drawn in red.

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Comment: This also explains why _“ends with the letter 't'”_ is correct— in that case, you're talking not about an instance of a “final letter 't'” of which there are many, you're talking about the “letter 't'” of which there is only one.  It comes down to whether you're talking about a usage or the symbol itself.

Comment: As I understood from your answer: i) We use “_a_” in { _"cat" has **a** final “t”_ } because there are many final t’s, for example in “bat”, “cat”, “format”, etc. That is, cat's final “t” is one of many. ii) We use “_the_” in { _**The** “t” in "cat" is final_ } because by adding the phrase { _in "cat"_ } after “_t_”, we don’t mean one of many final t’s which are in “bat”, “cat”, “format”, etc. We already mean the only “t” that’s in “_cat_”.

Comment: But if we consider the sentence “_The house has **a** cat in it_”, then by the logic above, we should say “_The house has **the** cat in it_” because by adding the phrase “_in it_” after “_cat_”, we don’t mean one of many cats living in the world. We already mean the only cat living in the house. Why does the logic which helped us before, lead to the error here?

Comment: Because there are many cats in the world, and you haven't identified the one in the house. "a" doesn't mean that you're referring to any item arbitrarily, just that you're referring to a member of a multi-item set that you haven't yet identified. By saying "the final 't' in 'cat'," you've identified it. But with "the house has a cat in it", you've just specified that some unknown cat is in the house. If the cat _is_ known, you can use "the", though in that case you'd invert the sentence to "The cat is in the house" (I'm not sure why that word order change happens).

Comment: It's a bit different for abstract things like "a final 't'": there are many such, but actually they're all identical (unlike cats), and so the only way to specify them is by specifying which word they're in. But I do think that's what's going on. Maybe another way of thinking of it is: when you say "'cat' has a final 't'", you're implicitly assuming that that final t's existence wasn't previously known, which means its identity couldn't have been specified. But when you say "the final 't' in 'cat' should be red", you're implicitly assuming its existence and specifically identifying it.

Comment: You can say “the house has the cat in it”, you’re just talking about a specific cat. For example: maybe you have a house and a cat, and the house has the cat in it. Meaning _your_ house has _your_ cat in it.

Comment: @Josh That sentence feels wrong to me, or at least awkward. But every variant of it feels fine: "the house has _my_ cat in it", or "that cat", or "the small cat", etc. I can't explain it, though.

Comment: It’s unnatural but I think it’s grammatically correct and logical… but I agree, it was a forced example.

Answer (score 23):

No, 1 is better. We choose between "a" and "the" based partly on context. Consider this:

> The house has a cat in it. The cat is black.

There is only one cat. And in the second sentence, we use "the" because we're talking about a specific cat. But in the first sentence, we're still establishing that context. We really mean "the house has one single instance of the category 'cat' in it," so we say "a cat" for that one.

Similarly, it makes sense to say "the word *cat* has a *t* in it." Having established that context, we might use "the" if we continue to discuss that letter that we just identified: "The *t* is the final letter."

EDIT: As I think about this more, I was puzzled why you might think that having "only one" of something would call for "the." After all, there are plenty of times that there would be just one of something, but "the" would be wrong. "There is a tree in our yard." Just one tree, but we wouldn't say "There is the tree in our yard." (Well, unless we were pointing at it.) I think maybe the source of your confusion is about proper nouns vs common nouns. There is only one Eiffel Tower. Ignoring replicas and models, there is only one "true" one in the world, and whenever we talk about it, we're talking about that one. In Paris, you would not say "Look, *an* Eiffel Tower!" With proper nouns we use "the" because we've already *specified* the single thing we're talking about. But cats, trees, and the letter "t" are common nouns. There are many cats, trees, and letter "t"s. We would use "a" when first identifying an *instance*, of them, and then could use "the" after having focused on that specific instance.

Comment: I notice I just used "the house" in my example. This would assume that this example was taken from a context that had already identified a specific house. Or sometimes, at the start of a story, it's used to "jump into" the action as if it's already been explained.

Comment: 'cat' has the final t phoneme of bat and fat.

Comment: OTOH: "The *t* in *cat* is its final letter." Now we're talking about a specific "t".

Comment: If we replaced "final" with "last", then would we use "a" too or only "the" would be correct?: _'Cat' has a/the last 't'_.

Comment: Using 'last' in this context makes it grammatically incorrect either way, unless you were talking about the last 't' in the sentence, and you had already refined context to indicate that it was the sentence you were talking about: "In this sentence, 'cat' has the last 't'."

Comment: @Loviii We don't say "last t" here. last t would mean there are other t's. The last train to London left 20 minutes ago. That means there were trains before than. Please do not use upper case c in your example in single quote marks. You are just multiplying the error.

Comment: **Her clothes were in tatters. The last t in that word** probably would be in the last syllable of the word.

Comment: You could say "The word 'cat' has the 't' last." which would mean "The 't' in 'cat' is the last letter of the word" and the 't' refers to the definitive article that is the singular 't' out of the letters in 'cat'. You could also say "The word 'cat' has a 't' last." where the 't' is an indefinite article referring to one of the infinite letter 't's that could exist. But you would not normally talk about "the last 't'." unless you are talking about a finite set of letter 't's such as "we had letters written on cardboard but the cat has stolen the last 't'".

Comment: Comments are not meant for extended discussion. @Loviii, if you have a new question, please open a new one. If you want to alter the present question, do it by editing.

Comment: @tsc_chazz Could you please come up with a context for the sentence "_'cat' has **a** last 't'_" in order for me to write it down into my documents? Thanks.

Comment: @Loviii I cannot think of any sentence where that would be grammatically correct.

Answer (score 2):

Remember, in the case of a definite article, you're indicating a specific thing.

If you're playing a word game in which you're making words up from a pile of letters, and you use the last letter "t" in the game to end the word "Cat", and someone asks you, "Where did the last 't' go?!?!?"

In that case, it would be perfectly accurate to say, "'Cat' has the final 't'." There may have been many 't's in the game, but that's the one you're talking about.

Otherwise, even though you're talking about the last 't' in 'cat', that 't' is a generic 't' that could be replaced with any other 't', so it wouldn't be proper to refer to it with a definite article.

Answer (score 1):

While the word *cat* only has one *t*, **there are lots of (letters) *t*** in different words.

In this sentence, *a* is correct instead of *the* because the *t* in that word is **just one of many used in many words.**

Using *the* would imply that no other word is spelled with a letter *t*.

Answer (score 1):

The sentences "'Cat' has a final 't.'" and "'Cat' has the final 't.'" are both plausible, but the one with "a" is much more likely, and the two sentences have different meanings.

The predicate "has a final 't'" expresses the normal, expected meaning: it is saying that there is a 't' there at the end. The sentence "'Cat' has a final 't.'" is essentially saying, "If you look at the last letter of the word 'cat,' you will notice that it is a 't.'"

On the other hand, the predicate "has the final 't'" is saying that something has **that one particular** 't' on the end of it. So one possible meaning of the sentence "'Cat' has the final 't.'" is, "If you look at the last letter of the word 'cat,' you will notice that it is that 't' that I mentioned a few minutes ago." Of course, that interpretation makes sense only if you really did mention a particular 't' a few minutes ago, and only if you intend to talk about that particular 't' again.

Another possible meaning of the sentence "'Cat' has the final 't.'" is, "If you look at the last letter of the word 'cat,' you will notice that it is the 't' which is the last letter of the word 'cat.'" But this is quite a strange thing to say, because it's completely unnecessary to point out that the word "cat" ends with the letter it ends with.

To summarize, the sentence "'Cat' has the final 't.'" is an unusual sentence that you would only say in unusual circumstances; the sentence "'Cat' has a final 't.'" is the correct sentence for expressing the usual meaning.